# SQL syntax error on sql 5.6.17

Tags: mysql, sql

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM person)
     SELECT id FROM connection
```

I get:
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM person) SELECT id FROM connection' at line 1

What's wrong?

I also tried

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM person)
BEGIN
SELECT id FROM connection
END
```

and get the same error.

Comment: are you trying to do this in a simple query or inside a stored procedure?

Comment: Can you post the complete query in which you are facing error?

Comment: I wanted to test selecting from connection table only if there exists records from person table. The complete query is above. Why doesn't it work? Both stand alone (SELECT name FROM person) and (SELECT id FROM connection) works, but doing the above query fails.

Comment: `IF` statements can only be used in stored procedures.

Comment: This is **not** a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a correct way. Rather try like

```
SELECT id FROM connection
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT name FROM person)
```

Answer (score 0):

`IF` can only be used in stored procedures. To do this in a regular query, do:

```
SELECT id FROM connection
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM person)
```

However, I wonder if this is really what you want. This will return **all** connection IDs if the `person` is empty, and return nothing if the `person` table has any rows. It doesn't relate the rows in the two tables to each other -- you would use a `JOIN` or correlated subquery for that.